# Django middleware process view after done with return render template continue to regular page

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-middleware

I created a custom django middleware,

```
class CustomMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, *view_args, **view_kwargs):
        ...
        ...
        return render(request, 'accounts/xyz_form.html', {})
```

Now in `xyz_form.html` there is a form which on submit action goes to url which call the view and view save the form data. Now after the form data is saved how can that form disappear after the view complete its execution and continue with its normal execution.

So what url should I pass in urls.py to call that view and on calling view the middleware gets exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disappear the form, you can use javascript to hide it or you can redirect page to another page where you want to continue with other code stuff. You can also go back to the home page with the following URL.

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
```